# Plenty of time, space, and money is needed or are needed?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions, quantifiers, compound-subjects

> Plenty of time, space, and money **is/are** needed

This was part of a question on indefinite pronouns. The textbook said *are* was the correct answer, but I still feel I would say *is*.

I was wondering if both are possible and which one you would be more likely to use.

Comment: 'is' means 'needed' refers to only money

Comment: What's the name of the textbook, and could you please include the author's name too? Did the author *explain* why "are" is the right answer?
 Thanks.

Comment: I would use 'is', because 'time, space, and money' are all encompassed by 'plenty'.

Comment: I'd consider time, space and money as being disparate enough to make singular agreement unacceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Although [MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/plenty) gives the part of speech for ***plenty*** as either pronoun or adverb, depending on usage, other dictionaries are careful to specify that in the case of ***plenty of + noun object(s)***, it is a quantifier (or noun?). From the [Collins English Dictionary:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/plenty)

> If there is plenty of something, there is a large amount of it. If there are plenty of things, there are many of them.
>
> Ex. There are plenty of cars on display here.

Notice that the number of the verb is plural to agree with the number of the noun object. By way of contrast...

> Ex. There was still plenty of time to take Jill out for pizza.

Once again, the verb agrees with the non-count noun "time".

Since there are several disparate (as Edwin Ashworth refers to them) items on your list, they should be considered as plural. i.e. You would say plenty of *them*, or *those items*, and not plenty of *that*; even though each one taken by itself would be a non-count noun taking singular agreement of the verb.

*[Random House Kernerman Webster´s College Dictionary](http://www.kdictionaries-online.com/DictionaryPage.aspx?ApplicationCode=18#&&DictionaryEntry=plenty&SearchMode=Entry)* agrees with Collins in this, but also says:

> usage: The construction PLENTY OF is standard in all varieties of speech and writing: plenty of room in the shed.
>  The use of PLENTY preceding a noun, without an intervening OF , first appeared in the late 19th century: plenty room in the shed. It occurs today chiefly in informal speech.

So, in your sentence we would have;

> Plenty of time, space, and money ***are*** needed

[Even though, somehow, someway, *is* sounds better to my ear. Go figure.]

Answer (score 0):

Time, space, and money are all singular nouns. As such, the correct conjugation would be "is". Note that all these words have plural forms (spaces, times, and moneys).

I am curious as to what the author of the books reasoning was. Could you provide us with the reference?

Comment: Singular nouns in a collection form a plural; however, in this case it would appear that "plenty" is the subject. And there is a difference between the usages of space v spaces, time v times, and money v monies.

Comment: You're applying the wrong rule: the "all singular noun phrases > singular verb agreement" is for noun phrases connected by the conjunction *or,* not noun phrases connected by the conjunction *and.*