# How is "plenty" a pronoun in "plenty of time"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, nouns, pronouns, dictionaries

The [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/plenty) list "plenty" as a pronoun. Example sentences include:

> I would have **plenty of time** to get home before my parents arrived
>
> There are shops **in plenty**

But **pronoun** by definition is a word that substitutes for a noun or noun phrase. How is "plenty" a pronoun in these examples? What noun/noun phrase does it substitute for? In contrast, Merriam Webster lists it as **noun**, not pronoun. I think in the sentence *You will have plenty to draw from* "plenty" is a pronoun, but it being a pronoun doesn't make sense in the two sentences above. How is the usage of "plenty" in those sentences different from that of these ones:

> I need **a large amount of money**.
>
> There was food and drink **in abundance**.

Both "amount" and "abundance" are listed as noun in dictionaries.

Comment: Related or possible dup https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388214/plenty-of-time-space-and-money-is-needed-or-are-needed?rq=1

Comment: See the answer by @Cascabel to this question, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388214/plenty-of-time-space-and-money-is-needed-or-are-needed?rq=1 
which starts:

“Although MacMillan gives the part of speech for plenty as either pronoun or adverb, depending on usage, other dictionaries are careful to specify that in the case of plenty of + noun object(s), it is a quantifier (or noun?)”

Comment: @Araucaria 1) I did not vote to close. Sorry if you were worried. 2) Cascabel's answer deals with the pronoun issue.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Sorry, I mistook that for the close-vote message!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Re 2), well kind of. They say "quantifier (noun?)". Have given a fuller answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The Original Poster is correct to be dubious about the parts of speech given by Oxford Dictionaries Online. In fact, one should be dubious about the part of speech information given in dictionaries, [as a general rule](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635). Dictionaries are wildly out of date regarding grammatical information, and effectively  ignore all of the developents in this area of linguistc science since about 1920. (There are good reasons for this as described in the linked-to post)

But then again, why look up grammar information in a dictionary? Dictionaries are great at lexicography, not grammar. It's best to look up grammar information in a modern vetted grammar book!

*The  Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002) gives the word *plenty* as a noun, not a pronoun. More specifically, they describe it as a number transparent quantificational noun.

They further write:

> *Plenty* is singular in form but does not admit any determiner or modifier: *plenty of butter/friends*, not * *a remarkable plenty of butter/friends* . (p.350)

The Original Poster's analysis and objections are generally very astute, apart from that even in *I have plenty to choose from*, the word *plenty* is still a noun. OP right, OD wrong!

Comment: What does *number transparent quantificational* mean? I know what each word means individually but placed next to each other they don't form a cohesion.  If "plenty" is classified as a noun, does that mean "lot" in "There are a *lot* of people who never eat sugar" is also a noun?

Comment: I believe in well argued points of view. "plenty of"  works grammatically just like "a lot of" or "lots of" ; those mean "much" or "many" depending on context. In other words, plenty is a noun used adjectivally. That term "transparent quantificational noun" is frankly, otiose. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA What else would you call _lot_ in that context but a noun? It has an indefinite article (determiner), it can be modified by adjectives (‘an awful lot of people’), it can be pluralised (‘lots of people’), etc. _Lot_ is much easier to class quite unambiguously and uncontroversially as a noun than _plenty_ is.

Comment: @Mari-Lou As to your question: _number-transparent_ means that in constructions like `an X of Y`, where X is the quantificational noun (QN), it is the _Y_ which determines the number of the whole noun phrase, even though _X_, not _Y_, is the head and ‘should’ be the determining factor. So ‘a lot of work **is** done’, but ‘a lot of errors **were** made’. This is as opposed to QNs which can force the NP to be either singular or plural and consequently are also used only with singulars or plurals (‘a great deal of work’ / ‘dozens of times’, but not ‘*a great deal of times’ / ‘*dozens of work’).

Comment: I’m not sure I buy H&P here. I find it just as likely that _plenty_ is a determinative mostly limited to fused-head constructions, rather than a noun which accepts no determiners or modifiers. Even H&P must accept that dialectal constructions like “there’s plenty time” are determinative, and “plenty more ideas” is clearly predeterminative. It does not seem irrelevant to me that _plenty_ is the only QN they mention which accepts absolutely no determiners or modifiers. At the very least, I’m not sure how you’d distinguish between such a noun and a fused-head determinative.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, words like *lot*, *bags*,  *loads*, *number*  etc are all (number transparent) quantificational nouns. *Lot*, for example, can take a determiner, and an adjective as a modifier: *an awful lot of people*, for example.  They are known as being number transparent because when they are subjects  and enter into constructions like *a lot of people* or *a lot of water*, the noun in the *of*-preposition phrase determines whether the verb is singular or plural: *a lot of people **are***, but *a lot of water **is***. This makes them strange. The word *lot* for example ...

Comment: @Mari-LouA ... is singular, which might make us expect that it should be *a lot of people is*, which of course is ungrammatical. Same goes with *loads*, which is plural. We might  reasonably expect *loads of water are*, but again this is ugrammatical. Because we associate quantity words in noun phrases with determinatives, people often take them to be deteminatives, but this is a mistake, because we need to  base their category on their syntax, not their meaning.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet But being in Determiner function doesn't preclude an item from  being a noun (phase). And noun phrases are excellent as modifiers of *more*: *hundreds more people*, *two miles more* and so forth. That doesn't mean that H&P are definitely right there. I'd suspect they based their analysis on a lot more research and evidence than that though (I'm sure John Payne, who is a renowned specialist on nouns and noun phrases, had a significant input there too). But, I'm sympathetic to your analysis - apart from ...

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ...that I'd expect any determinative to be able to freely function in Determiner function, which *plenty* can't at all in standard Englishes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sorry, didn't realise I was duping Janus's comments!

Answer (score 0):

*Plenty* entered English as a noun from Old French *plentee* or earlier *plentet* ‘abundance, profusion’ [in the mid-13th c.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/plenty?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_16490), though the partitive construction appears to be somewhat more recent:

> (a1398) * Trev. Barth.(Add 27944)   24b/b:  Blak eiȝen moueþ lasse for multitude & *[plente](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=144677443&egdisplay=open&egs=144708999)* [L multitudinem] of humours
>
> a1450 St.Editha (Fst B.3)   181:  [*Plentythe*](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=144724104&egdisplay=open&egs=144727674) of vitel þere was y-nowe.
>   a1450 St.Editha (Fst B.3)   519:  *Plenteythe* of fysshe þey hadden y-nowe.
>
> Wheat and rye have risen to a mark and 16s. a quarter. There is *[plenty](https://books.google.de/books?id=glY4AQAAMAAJ&q=%22plenty%20of%20old%20corn%22%20Henry&dq=%22plenty%20of%20old%20corn%22%20Henry&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE9Kq8vZreAhUCsKQKHeWPDFoQ6AEILDAC)* of old corn and new barley, oats, pease, and beans. — Lord Chancellor Audeley to Cromwell, 13 Sept. 1535 (*Letters and Papers, Foreign and Domestic, of the Reign of Henry VIII*, vol. ix, London, 1886).

If one admits *plenty* into the limited set of English [quantifiers](https://www.thoughtco.com/quantifier-grammar-1691558), such as *some, many/much, enough, all* or *few*, then a pronomial use should be uncontroversial:

> This competition has forced many smaller companies to go out of business, although [*plenty*](https://books.google.de/books?id=RWUiAQAAMAAJ&q=%22plenty+are+still+around%22&dq=%22plenty+are+still+around%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio7qXM2ZfeAhWrNOwKHQPKDJwQ6AEINDAD) are still around to compete with the big names of Pizza Hut, Domino’s, Little Caesar’s, and Papa John’s.  — Leonard M. Jessup, Joseph S. Valacich, *Information Systems Foundations*, 1999.
>
> Tucked away in corners of central Maine, [*plenty*](https://www.centralmaine.com/2018/06/23/the-world-cup-in-the-digital-age/) are still crazy about the most popular sport on the planet, Travis Barrett writes.  — “The World Cup in the digital age,” CentralMaine.com, 23 June 2018.
>
> My host in Paris once sent me across the city for what she promised was the best eclair, even though there were [*plenty*](https://www.nbcnews.com/better/business/7-things-your-airbnb-host-wants-tell-you-probably-won-ncna890546) available right around the corner. 
>   …
>   While there are a number of listings run as investment properties, complete with a property manager and call center if you call for help, *plenty* are still the original Airbnb idea — a room in someone's home, or their house that they vacate for you. — *NBC News*, 11 July 2018.
>
> If you want the hottest ticket in town [for *Hamilton*], [*plenty*](https://www.bostonglobe.com/arts/theater/dance/2018/10/09/the-high-cost-hamilton/hvBvv98WW7argV6EloDLDM/story.html) are still available through Ticketmaster. But be prepared to pay as high as $1500 apiece. — *Boston Globe*, 9 Oct. 2018.

If you replace *plenty* with *some* or *many* in these examples, you might change the relative quantity of pizza chains, eclaires, or theater tickets, but you won’t be changing the grammar: *plenty* functions identically to quantifiers used as pronouns.

As far as I’ve been able to determine, however, this use of *plenty* without a partitive *of*-phrase, as frequent as it is today,  doesn’t seem to predate the 19th c.:

> The merchants might as well be employed in the importation of foreign wheat, when [*plenty*](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/2188484?searchTerm=%22plenty+is%22) is to be procured in the home market,  — *The Sydney Gazette and New South Wales Advertiser*, 27 June 1827.
>
> “Mother wants your sifter, and she guesses you can let her have some sugar and tea, ’cause you’ve got [*plenty*](https://news.hrvh.org/veridian/cgi-bin/senylrc?a=d&d=newburghtelegraph18391031.2.3&txq=%22plenty+is%22).” — *Newburgh Telegraph* (NY), 31 Oct. 1839.
>
> I have only about one bushel of the Carolina, but [*plenty*](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=CF18550201.2.5&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522plenty+are%252522-------1) are to be had of Baker & Hamilton, Sacramento city. — J. S. Curtis, “California Pea-nuts,” *California Farmer and Journal of Useful Sciences*, 1 Feb. 1855.
>
> It is highly probable they will fall in with Indians, as [*plenty*](https://texashistory.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metapth232693/m1/1/zoom/?q=%22plenty%20are%22&resolution=1.5&lat=5756.311886642013&lon=4177.191806375346) are about. — *San Antonio Texan*, 12 Feb. 1857.

Even so, *plenty* as noun is far more frequent in 19th c. sources, appearing in contexts where contemporary speakers would likely say *an abundance, a sufficient number/amount of* or simply *plenty of*. One author draws a marked distinction:

> [*Plenty*](https://books.google.de/books?id=pJsWAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA736&dq=%22a+plenty+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8nsuY65neAhVCpI8KHe38DhYQ6AEIKTAB#v=onepage&q=%22a%20plenty%20of%22&f=false) is, however, more frequent in the literal sense for that which fills the body ; *abundance*, for that which fills the mind, or the desire of the mind: a *plenty* of provisions is even more common than an *abundance;* a *plenty* of food; a *plenty* of corn, wine, and oil : but an *abundance* of words; an *abundance* of riches; an *abundance* of wit and humour.  — George Crabb, *English synonymes explained in alphabetical order*, 1818 (repr.1978), 736.

This author apparently didn’t get the memo:

> A [*plenty of people*](https://books.google.de/books?id=cYdOAAAAMAAJ&q=%22a+plenty%22&dq=%22a+plenty%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo3NvLn5reAhVMZ1AKHXFjB1Y4FBDoAQgkMAA) die, or survive a long or acute illness but half alive, for want of efficient nursing.  — Anna Elizabeth Dickinson, *A Ragged Register: (of People, Places and Opinions)*, 1879, 120.

#### Pronoun, Yes or No?

While [Merriam-Webster](https://www.etymonline.com/word/plenty?ref=etymonline_crossreference#etymonline_v_16490) only lists *plenty* as a noun, adjective, or adverb, [MacMillan](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=144724104&egdisplay=open&egs=144727674) follows Oxford in giving it a pronomial use. I assume this decision rests with whether the editors wished to include the word as a quantifier in standard English or not. *CGEL*’s always singular “number transparent quantificational noun” never using a determiner sounds so overqualified as to be a subset of one. A few snips of Occam’s razor to this definition would suffice to parse *plenty* as a noun like *abundance*  or as a pronoun like *some* or *many*.

Comment: Merriam-Webster (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plenty) also lists *plenty* as a pronoun now.